# Access Query And Input Parameter With Case?

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access

I want to create a query that can be called from a .NET application that allows a parameter to be passed in. The parameter is a simple integer that will determine which statement to run. So I'd like the query to look something like...

```
CASE
    WHEN myParam = 0 THEN
        SELECT blah FROM blah;
    ELSE
        SELECT blah FROM blah;
END
```

I'm not familiar with Access all that much and finding it a pain in comparison to SQL Server... I hope this is possible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a single query, I believe that is not possible realize the work. You could try one of the following:

- Write one query for each query you want. After, in .NET application, decide which query to call, based on the original myParam;
- Write a function inside VBA and construct a dynamic query based on de myParam passed to the function; the query writes to a temporary table and the .NET application would first require the execution of the function and then query the temporary table.

I hope that this can help.

Best regards,

mpt

Answer (score -1):

This can be done

You can join string your query to satisfy conditions

```
strQuery ="CASE
                WHEN " + myParam + " = 0 THEN
                   SELECT blah FROM blah;
                ELSE
                   SELECT blah FROM blah;
           END"
```

During runtime the expression would be evaluated, eg: If I pass myParam as 0, it would executed as

```
CASE
    WHEN 0 = 0 THEN
        SELECT blah FROM blah;
    ELSE
        SELECT blah FROM blah;
END
```

Comment: Access SQL does not support `CASE ... WHEN`.

Comment: Is there another possible way to do this?

Comment: Looks like I can only return values if the expression is true or false, not execute a SQL statement. I may be wrong but I can't get it to work.